# How do I change the traversal order in dom4j? Is it possible at all?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, dom4j

I am trying to add an element to certain elements with dom4j, but the returned list of selected nodes is not in the order that I have expected. The added element should act as a counter to index the parent element with a running number. Have a look at this code snippet:

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document document = reader.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(fullString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
List<Node> filenameList = document.selectNodes("//ac:structured-macro[@ac:name='index-caption']/ac:rich-text-body/*[local-name()='p']/ac:image/ri:attachment/@ri:filename");
for (ListIterator<Node> iter = filenameList.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Node n = iter.next();
    System.out.println(n.getText());
}
```

This is my initial xml "fullstring" (pretty printed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ac:confluence PUBLIC "-//Atlassian//Confluence 4 Page//EN" "http://www.atlassian.com/schema/confluence/4/confluence.dtd" [<!ENTITY clubs    "&#9827;">
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
<!ENTITY ndash   "&#8211;">
<!ENTITY mdash   "&#8212;">]>
<ac:confluence xmlns:ac="http://www.atlassian.com/schema/confluence/4/ac/" xmlns:ri="http://www.atlassian.com/schema/confluence/4/ri/" xmlns="http://www.atlassian.com/schema/confluence/4/">
    <p>start</p>
    <ac:structured-macro ac:name="layout-boxes">
        <ac:parameter ac:name="layout">schritte</ac:parameter>
        <ac:parameter ac:name="title">First Level</ac:parameter>
        <ac:rich-text-body>
            <p>
                <ac:structured-macro ac:name="index-caption">
                    <ac:parameter ac:name="Prefix">Abb</ac:parameter>
                    <ac:parameter ac:name="Caption">Second Level</ac:parameter>
                    <ac:parameter ac:name="atlassian-macro-output-type">INLINE</ac:parameter>
                    <ac:rich-text-body>
                        <p>
                            <ac:image ac:height="250">
                                <ri:attachment ri:filename="rollinghills-2.jpg" />
                            </ac:image>
                        </p>
                    </ac:rich-text-body>
                </ac:structured-macro>
            </p>
            <ac:structured-macro ac:name="tip">
                <ac:parameter ac:name="title">Second Level</ac:parameter>
                <ac:rich-text-body>
                    <p>
                        <ac:structured-macro ac:name="index-caption">
                            <ac:parameter ac:name="Prefix">Abb</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:parameter ac:name="Caption">Third Level</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:parameter ac:name="atlassian-macro-output-type">INLINE</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:rich-text-body>
                                <p>
                                    <ac:image ac:height="250">
                                        <ri:attachment ri:filename="yosemite-13.jpg" />
                                    </ac:image>
                                </p>
                            </ac:rich-text-body>
                        </ac:structured-macro>
                    </p>
                </ac:rich-text-body>
            </ac:structured-macro>
        </ac:rich-text-body>
    </ac:structured-macro><p>
        <ac:structured-macro ac:name="index-caption">
            <ac:parameter ac:name="Prefix">Abb</ac:parameter>
            <ac:parameter ac:name="Caption">First Level</ac:parameter>
            <ac:parameter ac:name="atlassian-macro-output-type">INLINE</ac:parameter>
            <ac:rich-text-body>
                <p>
                    <ac:image ac:height="250">
                        <ri:attachment ri:filename="twinfalls.jpg" />
                    </ac:image>
                </p>
            </ac:rich-text-body>
        </ac:structured-macro>
    </p>
</ac:confluence>
```

My expected order is:

1. rollinghills-2.jpg
2. yosemite-13.jpg
3. twinfalls.jpg

If I test this in an online XPath tester, I get my expected order.

But in Java I get this output:

1. twinfalls.jpg
2. rollinghills-2.jpg
3. yosemite-13.jpg

The difference in these orders is, that in my expected order, dom4j/XPath traverses as deep as possible before going to the next sibling node. What dom4j/XPath actually does is: Get every match of level 1, get every match of level 2, get every match of level 3...

How do I change the traversal order?

Best regards
Hasenchartbreaker

Answer (score 0):

Writing my own treeWalk method(s) did the job:

```
public void treeWalk(Document document) {
    treeWalk(document.getRootElement());
}

public void treeWalk(Element element) {
        System.out.println("abb: " + abb);
        if (element.getQualifiedName().equals("ac:structured-macro")
                && element.attributeValue("name").equals("index-caption")) {
            Node filenameAttNode = element.selectSingleNode("./ac:rich-text-body/*[local-name()='p']/ac:image/ri:attachment/@ri:filename");
            System.out.println(filenameAttNode.getText());

        }

        for (int i = 0, size = element.nodeCount(); i < size; i++) {
            Node node = element.node(i);
            if (node instanceof Element) {
                treeWalk((Element) node);
            } else {
                // else
            }
        }
    }
```